# Rename columns in Python

Tags: python-2.7, rename, multiple-columns

My dataset's columns are named as hereafter:

```
ENE     ESE     East    NE  NNE     NNW     NW  North
```

I would like to insert an `'o_'` before each variable's name to get for instance `'o_ENE'`, `'o_ESE'`, etc. How can I automatize this ?

Comment: There is no need to edit the title with 'SOLVED'. You can simply accept the answer that helped you solve your problem, even if that answer was posted by you on your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've solved it, should have think about it before asking, sorry:

```
length=len(ds2.columns)
ds2_rename=[]
for i in range(length):
    ds2_rename.append('o_'+ds2.columns[i])
```